# bind and unbind along with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show a div `.overlay` to a user on click and the user must not be able to scroll or move from that page unless he clicks on it again and closes it.

So far i have tried with the below code and it works

```
 $('#clicker').click(function() {

            $(".overlay").toggle();

            $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

but the problem is when the user clicks again the div disappears but the scroll is missing.

i need to add the below code so it works...

```
 $('html').css('overflow', 'scroll');
 $('body').unbind('touchmove');
```

can someone help me on how unbind and add the above js code on the second click or toggled?

Comment: I achive this using `$("body").css({"overflow" : "hidden"});` and restore using `$("body").css({"overflow" : "scroll"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test the visibility of the overlay and execute the appropriate code:

```
$('#clicker').click(function() {
    if ($(".overlay").toggle().is(':visible') {
        $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    } else {
        $('html').css('overflow', 'scroll');
        $('body').unbind('touchmove');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add a conditional into the `touchmove` function, you can check if the div is shown, and decide like that:

```
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(e) {
  if($(".overlay:visible").length) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```